# Common terminal question on old furnace and air conditioner with new smart thermostat

Tags: hvac, furnace, air-conditioning, thermostat-c-wire

Trying to solve an odd problem with my T5 Lyric smart thermostat and an old furnace/AC.

I'll try and be concise.  The model of furnace is: Goodman, GMP075-4 Rev B

Details, and photos below for help:

1. Wiring from thermostat has 5 wires, normal.  The blue wire was not used, was tucked behind the thermostat.
2. The blue wire up at the furnace was not connected to anything.
3. The furnace is quite old, and formally only has a 3 wires on the control board: W, G, and R.
4. There is a blue wire that runs to the AC wiring, very likely a common for the AC (I think it's a common, insight would be good here.)
5. There is a transformer with 24 V lines coming off.

To try and get things running, I wire nutted the blue line from the thermostat wiring into the Blue line with the AC.  This got the thermostat running, and the system ran the heat just fine, but the AC would not power up at all, so I'm not sure what's happening.

I tried to put the blue line from the thermostat onto a grounded screw on the furnace that has a s, but that didn't do anything.

I tried to connect a separate 24V power source to the thermostat (kept original wiring at the furnace), and it got the system running with functional heat, but AC would not stay on.  Honeywell indicated a separate 24 V power source can't be used for the AC.

So... I'm stuck. I will likely try the Honeywell C-adapter: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07VMV2BJ7?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VMV2BJ7), but I'm afraid this won't work either.

It should seem that I should be able to find a common without the C-adapter, but I figured I'd ask y'all!  Just use Honeywell C-adapter?  If so, I'd still need to find a true common I think?

Pics below for what I got for wiring, etc.  Any thoughts/help would be appreciated!

https://photos.app.goo.gl/niT63t326s1betg76
https://photos.app.goo.gl/jgsAzZHgPNYHFByS7
https://photos.app.goo.gl/2exQXjJfGX8pu1jD8
https://photos.app.goo.gl/4LZAWaq78oGpBMto7

Answer (score 1):

### That light blue wire from the furnace is your C wire connection

Simply connect the blue wire from your thermostat cable in with the light blue wire from the furnace and the wire going to it from the condensing unit cable.    We know this is C because in order for your air conditioner to work, the 24V from R that your thermostat puts on Y needs to have a return path from going off to energize the compressor contactor coil, and that means the wire in the condensing unit cable that is not connected to Y must be connected to C.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but the AC would not turn on.  The thermostat turned on, it ran the heat just fine, but the AC would not kick on.

Comment: @thegreataus it sounds like you removed the C wire to the condensing unit from the splice when you made the connection -- all three C wires need to be in that splice for everything to work the way you want